# Entity Framework select by child table last state

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I have a problem with the following scenario. I have these tables

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TicketHistory](
[Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[TicketId] [int] NOT NULL,
[TicketStateId] [int] NOT NULL,
[Created] [datetime] NOT NULL,
[UserId] [int] NOT NULL,
[Note] [ntext] NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_TicketHistory_1] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
[Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
```

and

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Ticket](
[Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[TicketTypeId] [int] NOT NULL,
[TicketSourceId] [int] NOT NULL,
[TicketCategoryId] [int] NOT NULL,
[TicketPriorityId] [int] NOT NULL,
[UserId] [int] NOT NULL,
[Created] [datetime] NOT NULL,
[UniqueCustomerId] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_Ticket] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
[Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

for each ticket object there are one or more tickethistory.

I must select all the ticket where the last related tickethistory entry have a specific stateid...

How can I do this select using LINQ?

I'd like to do something like this:

```
var a = (from t in context.Tickets 
         where t.TicketHistories.OrderBy(x => x.Id).Last().TicketStateId == 1 
         select t).ToList();
```

but I get this error:

`LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'TicketHistory Last[TicketHistory](System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable1[TicketHistory])' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.`

Thanks in advance :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
var a = (from t in context.Tickets 
         where (t.TicketHistories.OrderByDescending(x => x.Id)).Take(1).SingleOrDefault().TicketStateId == 1 )
         select t).ToList();
```